# Streamlit clear fields of app do not work

Tags: python, streamlit

I'm trying to implement a simple front with the streamlit, this front will have a area to input a question and two bottons, 1 to submit and execute some action in the question and 1 to clear all (question and answer - the action over the question), but I cannot clear all the fields. Here is my code:

app.py

```
import streamlit as st

def question_and_answer_app():
    st.title("Question and Answer App")

    question = st.text_input("Enter your question:")
    answer_placeholder = st.empty()

    col1, col2 = st.columns(2)  

    if col1.button("Submit"):
        reversed_question = question[::-1]
        answer_placeholder.text("Answer: " + reversed_question) 

    if col2.button("Clear"):
        question = ""
        answer_placeholder.empty()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    question_and_answer_app()
```

Can someone give me a possible way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the argument of "key" to locate the widget and remove the input text.

```
import streamlit as st

def clear_text():
    st.session_state["input"] = ""

def question_and_answer_app():
    st.title("Question and Answer App")

    question = st.text_input("Enter your question:",  key="input")
    answer_placeholder = st.empty()

    col1, col2 = st.columns(2)

    if col1.button("Submit"):
        reversed_question = question[::-1]
        answer_placeholder.text("Answer: " + reversed_question)

    if col2.button("Clear", on_click=clear_text):
        answer_placeholder.empty()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    question_and_answer_app()
```

Comment: thank you very much, I think to use the argument of "key" but I did't know how, now it is clear.

Comment: I am trying to understand why I not pass explicit the "value" in st.text_input, it is passed direct de key. Can you explaim me why this please.

Comment: @Atilio The `value` of `text_input` when it first renders. It's similar to the default text when you haven't inputted anything. So when you need to change the text value, it will create a new widget instead of clearing it.