# How to clear input field after hitting Enter in streamlit?

Tags: python, widget, user-input, streamlit

I have a streamlit app where I want to get user input and use it later. However, I also want to clear the input field as soon as the user hits Enter. I looked online and it seems I need to pass a callback function to `text_input` but I can't make it work. I tried a couple different versions but neither works as I expect.

```py
import streamlit as st

def clear_text():
    st.session_state.my_text = ""

# This version doesn't clear the text after hitting Enter.
my_text = st.text_input("Enter text here", on_change=clear_text)

# This version clears the field but doesn't save the input.
my_text = st.text_input("Enter text here", on_change=clear_text, key='my_text')

st.write(my_text)
```

The expectation is to save the input into `my_text` and clear the field afterwards.

I looked at similar questions about clearing text input [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77016854/19123103) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76891261/19123103) but they're not relevant for my case because I want the input field to clear automatically while those cases talk about using a separate button. How do I make it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can slightly adjust the [*solution*](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/clear-input-box-after-hitting-enter/33824/2) provided by @[*MathCatsAnd*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18067541/mathcatsand) :

```
if "my_text" not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.my_text = ""

def submit():
    st.session_state.my_text = st.session_state.widget
    st.session_state.widget = ""

st.text_input("Enter text here", key="widget", on_change=submit)

my_text = st.session_state.my_text

st.write(my_text)
```

Output :

[image]

Comment: I had found that very answer after I posted this question and worked it out but thanks for posting it anyway. Streamlit discussion is a mess and in desperate need of moderation imo. Btw, it seems you don't need to initialize `my_text` in the beginning if you use `.get()`.